# Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n| = |a|$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = a$. Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n| = |a|$.

First of all, I wonder about what does it mean the statement. I am just studying the theory today. I actually know that $a_n$ is the general term of a sequence (and of a series). i.e. it should equal the formula which gives the pattern of the sequence. If we plug a number in the n of the formula, we get the output for the number plugged in. Instead, does $a$ stand for the cluster point of a sequence, right?

Could you show me the proof of the statement above and tell me if I misunderstood something in my wording, please?

Comment: maybe I can derive the statement that has been to be proved directly by the definition of convergence:

Comment: exists an "a" such that the limit which tends to infinity of the general term of the sequence is equal to the cluster point if and only if for every epsilon > 0 exists n(epsilon) which appartains at N such that the absolute value of an - a < epsilon  etc.

Comment: Hint: Prove the following inequality: $| |a| - |b| | \leq |a-b|$

Comment: Sorry, there is a mistake in my period in the first comment: ""maybe I can derive the statement that have to be proved..."

Comment: Are you aware that if $f(x)$ is a continuous function, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(a_n)=f(a)$? In this situation, $f(x)=|x|$ is continuous. If you are required to prove this from the definition, then Nigel Overmars hint is all that is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $lim_{n{\rightarrow}{\infty}} a_n=a$

Then for each $\epsilon>0$ , there is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that for each $n>N$ , $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$.

By triangle inequality , we have $|a+b|\leq |a|+|b| \Rightarrow ||a|-|b||\leq |a-b|.$

So observe that $||a_n|-|a||\leq|a_n-a|$

Since $|a_n-a|<\epsilon \Rightarrow ||a_n|-|a||< \epsilon$

Therefore $lim_{n{\rightarrow}{\infty}} |a_n|=|a|$ for each $n>N$.

Comment: It's a pleasure to help you.

Answer (score 1):

We don't need to know the exact values of a sequence in order to talk about it.  To say that there is a sequence {$a_n$} means nothing more than we have a countable set of values in an order.  It doesn't mean anything about whether we have a definition for them.

In practical use we often (but far from always) do have a definition for otherwise we may have no method of predicting or describing the sequence.  But there's no reason in to assume that in talking about a sequence we can predict or describe it.

In this case the only thing we know about this sequence is that it converges to a real number we have labeled $a$.  The definition of a limit explains what that means.  (*For every $\epsilon$ > 0 then there is a large M such that for all   $n> M$ then the $a_n$ terms are less than $\epsilon$ away from a; i.e |$a_n - a| < \epsilon$.*)  You need to show by this definition, that the limit of the absolute values of this sequence (whatever the **** the sequence actually is) that the absolute values converge to the absolute value of the original limit.

HINT:  if you follow the definition of converges precisely not hard.  If |a - b| < c, then what can be said about ||a| - |b||?